# Log4j2 throws file permission exception when multiple users run the program

Tags: java, linux, log4j, log4j2

The current implementation of our application uses Log4j2 for logging. The application is designed to be run by different users.

We've observed an issue where if one user runs the program and a log file is created, subsequent users are not able to run the program and a file permission exception is encountered. It appears the log file, once created by the first user, cannot be accessed by other users due to permission restrictions.

This behavior prevents multiple users from running the application concurrently, which is a required functionality.

1. User A runs the program, triggering the creation of a new log file.
2. User B attempts to run the program.
3. User B encounters a file permission exception.

   ```
        <RollingFile name="log_file"
                     fileName="/var/applog/myapp/aggregator/aggregator_rest.log"
                     filePattern="/var/applog/myapp/aggregator/aggregator_rest.%i.log.gz" 
                     filePermissions="rwxrwxrwx">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="log_file"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
   ```

Comment: put the logfile in a user specific directory

Comment: that is not possible

Comment: Why it is not possible?

Comment: All logs should be in same file.

Comment: What operating system are you using?   Because it appears that the `filePermission` attribute is only understood if the default file system supports posix permissions.  If not, it appears that value of the attribute is ignored ... with a log warning.  See https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/2.x/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/FileManager.java#L130.

Answer (score 0):

You have far bigger problems.

If you solve the access rights issue, which is easy enough, you have multiple separate processes all writing to the same file. This will result in:

HeHelloo, WWoorrldld

style craziness in that file, with log strings interleaving and logs just missing entirely.

In the comments you say: "It has to be one file". Okay. This will take you weeks of hardship to build, that is an *incredibly* costly requirement. Still convinced you want it? Well, hold on to your seat then:

### The usual way: Separate process

Have all apps send data concurrently to a 'logging process', which is an entirely separate JVM that is started on boot and runs forever. Processes can e.g. do that by connecting to them using TCP/IP connections (there are also pipes but java makes that rather difficult).

That separate process can simply write to the log file, and can do its own queueing and can ensure logs are written in receipt order and without log messages mixing together into long gobbledygook.

Of course, if that log service is down or crashes, all apps will just have to crash on boot and say 'no can do, start the log service first'.

### Lock files

An alternative is to involve lock files - to log a message, first, atomically create `mylogfile.log.lock`. If this succeeds, open the log file, append the log message, close the log file, then delete the lock file.

If this fails, throw some dice (call `rnd.nextInt()`) to determine a random amount of milliseconds to wait, then try again. (the randomness is CRUCIAL. Ever walk on the street and you're about to bump into someone, so you hang left but they also hang left, then you hang right and they also hang right? Computers can do that too, except because computers do the exact same thing if given the exact same inputs, they are wont to do it forever. You MUST introduce chaos or this is not solvable!)

This is quite inefficient and means any attempt to log something is potentially very very slow.

It also means if one of the apps is hard-killed or hard-crashes, the log lock file remains, so all processes need to check how often they retry to acquire the lock, and after 4 seconds or so, should report: Hmm, hey, user? Maybe that lock file is an orphan, here it is - if you have determined it is, please delete the lock file and only then will I continue operation.

This is all highly complex, of course.

### The same principles, but pre-bundled

These concepts are already exist: **Databases**. Require that users have a concurrency-capable database (So, **you cannot** just run H2 or some other in-java-process DB in each app and have them all attempt to open the same DB, that will fail - it needs to be a separate process), and write logs to the database. There is no file *at all* in this scenario, there's a database (which will be stored as a bunch of binary files, of course).

### Ad-hoc server

The OS will only let one process open a TCP/IP server port and will close it if that process dies, even if it is hard-killed. Any app can do the following trick:

- On boot, attempt to open a ServerSocket on port 14525 (something between 1024-40000, pick any number, pray it doesn't clash with any other software's choice).
- If it works, great, start listening for 'log push' messages on that port, and open the log file. You write your logs, as well as any received on the port, to it.
- If it does not work, connect to it instead. As long as it continues to accept connections, don't write logs, instead send them to that process. If this fails, try to open the port (hey, maybe the 'log hoster' app has been quit).

These things are all **extremely** complicated.

### Script it

Make a dir, each user gets their own log file, some separate cronjob flies by, and concats them all to a central log file.

This doesn't work well if you want a guarantee that log messages are properly interleaved (if log message A is in the log file before B, that this means A must have happened before B). Strict interleaving **is interprocess communication** and therefore is not possible without locks. Hence why this is vastly more complicated than 'everybody opens the same file and writes to the same place'.

### Sidenote: Access rights

If multiple processes need to be able to write to the same file, you need to create the log file with the appropriate access rights. Check the `java.nio.file.Files` API for how to do that.

Comment: That is correct, but at same time only one user can run the program. after program finished, another user can run the program.

Comment: You wrote: _This behavior prevents multiple users from running the application concurrently_ - and now you comment the opposite. You should put way more effort and care in formulating your question next time. This answer correctly answers the text of your question. You now have a different question. You'll have to start a new question for that.

Comment: Sorry, it is my mistake. Thank you for your answer.
Did you have any ideas based on my previous comment.